# How does numpy store an image array?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I imported a picture as NumPy array, and I thought the data structure should like `[[255, 255, 255][255,255,255]...[255, 255, 255]` because of the RGB colour. However, the real structure is:

```
[[225 225 225 ... 233 232 233]
 [225 225 225 ... 233 233 233]
 [226 226 225 ... 233 232 233]
 ...
 [225 226 225 ... 233 233 233]
 [226 226 225 ... 233 232 233]
 [226 226 226 ... 232 233 234]]
[[225 225 225 ... 233 232 233]
 [225 225 225 ... 233 233 233]
 [226 226 225 ... 233 232 233]
 ...
 [225 226 225 ... 233 233 233]
 [226 226 225 ... 233 232 233]
 [226 226 226 ... 232 233 234]]
```

And when I print it one by one, just like the previous code is `Img` and this is `Img[0]`, strange things happen.

```
[225 225 225 226 226 226 225 226 226 225 255 226 226 226 222 228 255 228
 226 226 226 226 226 226 226 226 228 226 228 226 226 228 228 226 226 228
 226 226 255 228 226 226 226 226 228 228 228 255 255 228 228 228 228 228
 228 229 228 228 228 228 228 222 228 228 228 228 226 228 228 228 228 226
 255 228   0 226 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 226 228 228 228 228   0
 226 226 228 228 255 226 228 228   0 228 228 228 228 228 228 255 228 228
 228 228 228 228 228 226 225 224 226 226 228 228 228 226 225 228 228 228
 228 228 228 228 226 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 228
 228 228 228 228 228 228 228 229 228 228 228 229 228   0 228 228 228 229
 228 228 229 229 229 229 255 229 229 229 229 229 229 229 228 228 228 228
 229 229 229 229 228 229 229 229 229 229 230 229 229 229 229   0 229 229
 229 229 230 229 229 231   0 231 229 230 230 231 229 231 230 231 231 230
 230 230 231 230 232 232 232 230 232 231 230 231 230 232 229 231 231 232
 232 230 232 232 231 231 232 231 232 233 232 233 232 232 231 232 233 233
 232 233 232 231 232 231 233 255 233 233 232 233 233 233 232 232   0 233
 233 233 233 233 233 232 231 233 232 233 233 231 233 233 233 233 231 233
 233 233 233 232 233 233 232 233 255 233 234 233 232 232 234 231 234 233
 233 233]
```

What's the meaning of the numbers and what's the real structure of the NumPy image array?

Thanks!

Comment: Img = numpy.array(Image.open("./saltpepper.bmp"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a grayscale image, that is why you have a 2D array. If it was a color image, it would have three channels, hence, a 3D array.

Comment: I think that's the problem. Thanks. :)